# How to customize the path for my images

Tags: html, css, image, styling

Ok, the path to the images of my site is often the full URL to the image. Starting with http://

I don't want this, because when the site is finished I need to move it to a new domain, then all images don't work anymore.

But I can't figure out what I must give as a path for the images to be displayed correctly.

My full addres is now: http://mysite.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/image.png

I want to call images from /wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/image.png

or better: /images/image.png

How do I make this working for both stylesheets and normal pages in all cases? Stylesheets are in a different dir named /interio_child/stylesheets/

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths.

In css for example your can use "../images/image.png" assuming that your css lies in "wp-content/themes/interio_child/css/mycss.css" and the image in "wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/image.png"

In your script you can use variables like "$template-path = 'themes/interio_child/';" and access the image using "$imagepath = $template-path.'images/image.png';"

Comment: This looks promising. Gonna try it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

suppose your images are in "images" folder and your page is in "Page" folder then , you need to specify:

```
src="../images/image.png"
```

if your images are in "images" folder and your page is in "page2" sub folder under "page" folder  then , you need to specify:

```
src="../../images/image.png"
```

simply you need to know just level of sub directory...